# A small key-length PHP cipher

Tags: php, hash, decode, encode, hmac

I've been searching around like mad looking for a ciper that can take a secret word, whilst also providing a small character length, something between 30-45.

example string: "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

Since this code will be sent via $_GET in url from and to and will also be receiving via url, I want it to be as short as possible between 30-45, with a salt so I can decode it on the other end.

I have scoured several ciphers such as these:
http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php

But so far either they either return huge 50+ characters, or have characters outside of [a-z][A-Z][0-9] such as padding '==' but couldn't find anything I'm looking for.

I found the following hashing algo, which has the short character length whilst also a secret code. But this method does not allow decoding, alternative being is to see if two keys match using this method

```
<?php
echo hash_hmac('ripemd160', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', 'secret');
?>
b8e7ae12510bdfb1812e463a7f086122cf37e4f7
```

Is there a ciper that can do both secret word and be encoded/decoded whilst providing a short character length?

Comment: What's wrong with the `==` padding? base64 encoding seems adequate as long as you remove this restriction.

Comment: What you're looking for is **compression**, not encryption. You may also encrypt your value in addition to that, but the primary question here is about compression. And it's pretty hard to compress something into a small size while keeping the used alphabet constant. What you want mostly doesn't exist.

Comment: hi nickb, the base64 encoding still produces large character set

Comment: hi deceze, so does this mean that it can not be done easily? So my only option maybe using the hash_hmac and comparing values?

Comment: What exactly is your use case to begin with?

Comment: I mentioned above in post. It will be used to send and receive variables through $_get in urls. Thats why need it to be relatively short

Comment: A few more details maybe? Does it *have* to be passed as query parameter? Are the values too long if you don't compress them? Sessions or POST is not an option? Any form of server side storage is not an option? If you'd hash them, what would you do then? What do you have to compare them to?

Comment: Sorry yes they have to be passed via query parameter. Values do end up being far too long. Session or POST not an option as the third party API can only send and receive url variables. I can save on server side no problem but their API accepting will not accept such a large character set

Comment: Every hashing method is only one way.  So just ignore any kind of hash because although the hmac gave you a good character set, you'll never recover the original data.  Base64 gives you the proper character set, but takes every 1 character and spreads it into 3 chars.  It sounds like you need LZW Compression.  But it returns UTF-8 characters by default. So you'd need to modify the standard implementation.  So if you were to do that, then whoever is sending you the data also has to make a custom version of your encryption method.  Which it sounds like you don't have that kind of control.